# Array class design: how to share interface among sparse/dense storage, arrays and sub-arrays?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

My goal is to create a 2D array class with dense or sparse storage, with support for sub-matrices. 
I want to be able to have either dense storage ( std::vector) or sparse ( std::map )
I also want to be able to have sub-matrices that pretty much use the same get/set interface

Mock classes below:

```
struct ArrayBox
{
    int w,h,x,y;
    bool in_range(...)
};

template<class T>
struct DenseArray2D
{
    ArrayBox box;
    std::vector<T> data;

    T& get(x,y)
    // etc
}

template<class T>
struct SparseArray2D
{
    ArrayBox box;
    std::map<size_t, T> data;

    T& get(x,y)
    // etc, interface identical to above
}
```

Now, how can I add support for subarrays into this so that I write as little identical code as possible? The only differenceof the subarray is that it has a reference to the data (given in the ctor) and a different box

The above design is of course not set in stone, so any suggestions welcome.

Comment: This can be a huge (or never-ending) project if the design is to be "right" according to a number of aspects. Why don't you first consider using an existing library?

Comment: I want to avoid code bloat and dependencies: I have a simple feature set required, which probably fits in a few hundred lines of code.

Comment: I see, I have passed through this stage several times and I am also a victim of this illusion. Anyhow, your question is still too generic and I wouldn't know where to start. Just for an idea, you may check my own view of what e.g. an 1-dimensional [indirect array](https://github.com/iavr/ivl2/blob/master/include/ivl/root/core/array/view/indirect.hpp) view and its [iterator](https://github.com/iavr/ivl2/blob/master/include/ivl/root/core/array/iter/indirect.hpp) might look like. 2D subarrays should be much more complicated and I'm not there yet. Of course, I have different standards.

Comment: Thanks for the code! it certainly looks over-the-top for me though, I have simpler needs atm :)

Comment: By the way, chapter 29 of the [4th edition](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) of Stroustrup's classic book, "A Matrix Design", could be a good place to start. It has similar goals to yours, it is N-dimensional, quite more generic (but not sparse), stores data in an internal vector like you do, and still fits in a chapter with almost-complete code.